# Remove "...[C[0k" from expect output

Tags: unix, scripting, expect, csh

How can I not generate the substring "...[C[C[C[0k" after issued comands trough expect scripts?
For example, I have the following lines in an expect script:

```
#set variables, parameters etc
...
spawn telnet $IP $PORT
expect -nocase "name:"
send -- "$USER\r"
expect -nocase "password:"
send -- "$PASS\r"
expect -re "$prompt"
send -- "terminal length 0\r"
expect -re "$prompt"
send -- "show vlan\r"
expect -re "$prompt"
send -- "logout\r"
expect eof
```

After execution I receive the undesirable substrings:

```
Username:[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0Kadmin
Password:[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0K**************
switch#
[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0Kterminal length 0
switch#[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0Kshow vlan
...
#'show vlan' command result here
...
switch#[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0Klogout
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Does anyone have a tip on how can I not generate these "[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[0K" strings? Other issue is that **I cannot use other tool**(sed, awk, tr etc) to remove the strings, I need that expect not generate then at first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect is not generating these, it is the Cisco telnet service that you are connecting to. It sends escape sequences to do stuff like changing colours.

You could try changing the TERM variable before calling expect, or setting it in your expect script before the `spawn telnet` command. Try setting TERM=unknown. Otherwise look into the arguments that your telnet program supports to disable escape sequences.